# Using `SUMPRODUCT` without dividing by zero

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

[image]

See the image above for my hypothetical grade sheet in Libre Calc. There are two rows. One contains the points achieved for each assignment while the second records the points available. I would like to keep a running average of the grades, but I do not wish to update the formula for the running average each time a new assignment is added. Currently, I am using:

```
SUMPRODUCT( ENTIRE_POINTS_ACHIEVED_ROW, 1 / (ENTIRE_POINTS_AVAILABLE_ROW) )
```

I then find the average by dividing by the number of non-blank rows, using `COUNTA()`.

As you can see above, assignments 1-3 are complete, but there is no information for the fourth. Because of this, I get a divide by zero error. How can I accommodate for this? Or, is there a more straightforward way to achieve what I've described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Scott Craner proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260996/342546) , using an **Array formula** is the way to follow. With LO Calc, the following formula should work (enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array formula):

> `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2:E2<>0; B2:E2; "");1/B3:E3)/COUNT(B2:E2)*100`

[image]

<sup>*I've adapted an [example from the OpenOffice.org Calc documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Average.2C_ignoring_zero_entries) for this.*</sup>

Comment: This works perfect, thanks. I wasn't aware of the concept of an "array formula". I'll should probably look into that when I have a little time.

Comment: Currently, it seems to only take into account that the numerator (row 2, points achieved) being 0, but it not that the denominator (row 3, points available) being 0 which was what the question asked..? (Compare with the answer by Scott Craner which is correct.)

Comment: @Magne - no, you got the question wrong. There's no point calculating a running average on the points available, because they are always 100. Additionally, maybe you missed the identical result of both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this array formula instead:

```
=SUM(IF($B$3:$E$3<>"",B2:E2/B3:E3))/COUNT(B2:E2)
```

Being an array it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. If done properly `{}` will be put around the formula.

This is excel,  It may not work in LibreOffice.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks. This works but the formula is slightly off. This takes the product of (1/3) * (2/4) * (3/5) and then divides by the count. This works if we change `PRODUCT` to `SUM`, for example. On the other, hand it looks like tohowahwohu has posted an answer using `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester 1/3 = .33333, 2/4 = .5 and 3/5 = .6; then .3333 * .5 * .6 = .1; then .1 / 3 = .0333333  I don't see where this is the wrong answer.

Comment: That's correct, but it's not the average of the 3 grades; it's the product of the 3 grades, divided by 3.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester you are correct I went the wrong way. I will edit.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester see edit.  If you are more comfortable with the other answer then mark it correct, they both get the same place so its your choice.  Happy to accept either.